# Prometheus data for Grafana XY chart

Tags: python, prometheus, grafana

I am using a python query exporter for prometheus ([here](https://github.com/albertodonato/query-exporter)) which I am using to get data into Grafana. The Prometheus metrics look something like:

```
# HELP Usage Usage
# TYPE Usage gauge
Usage{Manager="man1",database="db"} 8.932365597777797e+06
Usage{Manager="man2",database="db"} 7.306852720000009e+06
Usage{Manager="mn3",database="db"} 6.8991086356944535e+06
# HELP Group_Outputs Outputs
# TYPE Group_Outputs gauge
Group_Outputs{Manager="man1",database="db"} 2.0
Group_Outputs{Manager="man2",database="db"} 4.0
Group_Outputs{Manager="man3",database="db"} 6.0
```

I would like a scatter plot with the outputs vs Usage for each manager, but when I try to create it I can only select one data source, either outputs or Usage - and cant see a way of including them both.

Should the exporter be coming the metrics somehow for this, or is there a way to combine two metrics in Grafana?

Comment: Is this `Manager="mn3"` a typo?